# x64 if Visual Studio C++ 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, x86, 64-bit, sdl

I have been using SDL with Visual C++ for a while, mostly making practice games, but I find that I can't give the game to other people unless they have Visual C++ themselves.  One problem that I found using a Dependency Tracker was that the source files and such used both x86 *and* x64.  After looking through, I found that my Visual Studio source files were all in x64, so naturally I went through and modified my SDL files to be the x64 package instead of the x86.  After fussing about how it still insisted on not working, I found out that the program that I was exporting was in x86 all along!  I've been trying since to get it to export in x64 since, but I simply don't know how.  Can somebody help me do this?

Comment: What methods have you tried?

Comment: Thus far, just looking to see if there is an obvious way to set it to export in x64.

Comment: Source files (.cpp) do not _use_ x86 and x64. They usually can be _compiled_ for both types of processor, though. Standard C++ code can even be compiled for x86, x64, ARM, MIPS, Itanium and a few dozen other types of CPUs. Also, "I was exporting ... " isn't exactly standard terminology either. And what is "Dependency Tracker"? Computers are rather unforgiving when it comes to sloppiness, especially computer programs intended for professionals.

Comment: Has my answer been of any help?

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, this question is a bit hard to understand for me. It looks, like MSalters suggested, that you mix up some terms.

The source of your problem is probably just the missing Visual Studio Redistributable on the target computer.

You can get it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679). Not that this is the redistributable for VS 2012 Update 1. There are also different versions for x86 and x64 (also arm). Depending on what your output is, you have to deliver the right version of the redistributable with you programms.